# ORA-12700: invalid NLS parameter value. (nls_numeric_characters)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

First of all you have to know that I am not DBA at all  (i'm web dev) and my knowledge in Oracle is very limited. 
Since 2 days i'm facing a big problem since my server has reboot for a unknown reason.
Before the machine reboot by itself, everything was working good with my oracle instance. I could use SQL Developer to check the datas, I could send request from a ASP.NET/C# application etc.
The configuration was made by a person who is no more with me now, I can't ask his help at the moment.

After the machine did reboot nothing worked right. First of all, I mentioned the problem when I tried to open my database from SQL Developer the following message was displayed :

```
    Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Then I launched sqlplus from command prompt and did as follow just to try :

```
C:/>sqlplus /nolog
SQL>conn sys/sys as sysdba
SQL>startup
ORA-12700: invalid NLS parameter value. (nls_numeric_characters)
```

here we go. 
I searched all over the internet and found no solution. I found it was probably caused by "spfilexe.ora" which contains the line "*.nls_numeric_characters='.'"
I tried "*.nls_numeric_characters=',.'" and other combination, nothing worked.

I also tried to create pfile from spfile, then remove the "nls_numeric_characters" line from pfile and try :

```
    startup pfile='<file_url>'.
```

The database was mounted but in exclusive mode :

```
    Instance ORACLE lancÚe.

    Total System Global Area  285212672 bytes
    Fixed Size                  1287016 bytes
    Variable Size             226495640 bytes
    Database Buffers           54525952 bytes
    Redo Buffers                2904064 bytes
    ORA-01102: montage de base de donnees en mode EXCLUSIVE
```

Then after it is mounted if i try to access to the database it returns the ORA-12514 message.

I'm running Oracle 10.2.0 on Windows Server 2003.

(Sorry for my approximative english, I do my best to be understood!)

Thanks

EDIT1:

```
SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\flash_r
                                                 ecovery_area
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 10G
SQL> select * from v$flash_recovery_area_usage;

FILE_TYPE    PERCENT_SPACE_USED PERCENT_SPACE_RECLAIMABLE NUMBER_OF_FILES
------------ ------------------ ------------------------- ---------------
CONTROLFILE                   0                         0               0
ONLINELOG                   ,98                         0               2
ARCHIVELOG                    0                         0               0
BACKUPPIECE                   0                         0               0
IMAGECOPY                     0                         0               0
FLASHBACKLOG                  0                         0               0

6 ligne(s) sÚlectionnÚe(s).

rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Lun. Juin 15 15:47:21 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

connectÚ Ó la base de donnÚes cible (non dÚmarrÚe)

RMAN> crosscheck archivelog all;

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: Úchec de la commande crosscheck Ó 06/15/2015 15:47:30
RMAN-12010: Úchec d'initialisation de l'allocation automatique de canal
RMAN-06403: impossible d'obtenir une session avec toutes les autorisations
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

EDIT2:
When i enter the following command :

```
SQL> show parameter nls;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_calendar                         string
nls_comp                             string
nls_currency                         string
nls_date_format                      string
nls_date_language                    string
nls_dual_currency                    string
nls_iso_currency                     string
nls_language                         string      AMERICAN
nls_length_semantics                 string      CHAR
nls_nchar_conv_excp                  string      FALSE
nls_numeric_characters               string

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_sort                             string
nls_territory                        string      AMERICA
nls_time_format                      string
nls_timestamp_format                 string
nls_timestamp_tz_format              string
nls_time_tz_format                   string
SQL>
```

Language is AMERICA while it should probably be FRANCE. Is that a normal behaviour ou do I have to edit something?

Comment: What is the value in your Registry for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Your Oracle Home Name}\NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, resp. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Your Oracle Home Name}\NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`?

Comment: Hi, there is no line with label "NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS" in  : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Your Oracle Home Name}\NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.

Comment: What happens if you `alter database open`, or shutdown and start up from the pfile again? Does the alert log give any hints? You won't be able to connect remotely until the DB is open normally and has registered with the listener.

Comment: Listener would be the first thing I would check. Make sure you've started up the Listener. The next thing would be to check you TNSname.ora file and check the TNS names are setup correctly. Have you setup your ORacle home in the System Environmental variables? You also need a TNS Admin setup: set TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE HOME%\network\admin

Comment: when I enter "alter database open;" the following error message is displayed (sorry it is french msg) :
_

ERREUR Ó la ligne 1 :
ORA-00313: Úchec d'ouverture des membres du groupe de journaux 1, thread 1
ORA-00312: journal en ligne 1 thread 1 :
'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_7SBL387D_.LOG'
ORA-27041: ouverture du fichier impossible
OSD-04002: ouverture impossible du fichier
O/S-Error: (OS 2) Le fichier sp┐fi┐st introuvable.

Comment: The environement variable look right, then listener.ora and tnsnames.ora also look right. Maybe my lack of knowledge in oracle makes me miss something important... idk

Comment: Hmm.. Can you run this? show show parameter db_recovery_file_dest

Comment: the following result is displayed: SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest

`SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest


NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\flash_recovery_area

db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 10G`

Comment: You got RMAN running? I'm thinking your logs are too big? If you're on a XE DB you've got 4Gb limitations.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1106838

Comment: I edited my question, see EDIT1

Comment: re-edited, more details about nls